# Python: add columns to dataframe from another with matching "vlookup"

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'd like to add two columns to an existing dataframe from another dataframe based on a lookup in the name column.

Dataframe to update looks like this:

| Player | School | Conf | Cmp | Att |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Danny Wuerffel | Florida | 1 | 708 | 1170 |
| Steve Sarkisian | Brigham Young | 0 | 528 | 789 |
| Billy Blanton | San Diego State | 0 | 588 | 920 |

And I'd like to take the height and weight from this dataframe (actually a json file) and add it based on matching Player names:

| Name | School | Conf | Height | Weight | Pct | Yds |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Danny Wuerffel | Florida | 1 | 6-2 | 217 | 60.5 | 10875 |
| Steve Sarkisian | Brigham Young | 0 | 6-3 | 230 | 66.9 | 7464 |
| Billy Blanton | San Diego State | 0 | 6-0 | 222 | 63.9 | 8165 |

Codewise I tried something like this so far:

```
existing_dataframe['Height'] = pd.Series(height_weight_df['Height'])
```

But I'm missing the part matching them on the name because the DFs aren't in the same order

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us try

```
existing_dataframe = existing_dataframe.merge(height_weight_df[['Name','School','Height','Weight']],left_on=['Player','School'],right_on=['Name','School'],how='left')
```

Comment: Won't this add all columns from the height_weight_df though?

Comment: @MJ95 filter it before merge

Comment: sorry, I'm a python newbie, how would that be done?